# how to put mongodb items in variables for discord bot?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, discord, discord.js

**This is the model:**

```
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

module.exports = mongoose.model(
    "Leveling",
    new Schema({
      guildID: { 
          type: String
      },
      guildName: {
          type: String
      },
      roletoad: {
          type: String,
          default: "null"
      },
      roletoremove: {
          type: String,
          default: "null"
      },
      rolelevel: {
          type: Number,
          default: 0
      },
    })
  );
```

**This is the command to get all leveling roles in a specific guild:**

```
if(args[0]==="list"){
    const del = await Leveling.find({
        guildID: message.guild.id,
    },{ 
        _id: 0,
        roletoad: 1,
        roletoremove: 1,
        rolelevel:1
    })
        
    return await message.channel.send(del)
}
```

**This is the output:**

```
{
  roletoad: '735106092308103278',
  roletoremove: '731561814407774248',
  rolelevel: 5
}
{
  roletoad: '735598034385371167',
  roletoremove: '744562691817078905',
  rolelevel: 7
}
```

I want to know how to get each item(roletoad,roletoremove,rolelevel) in a specific variable.

Comment: To be clear, you're getting an array of objects from the db, right?

Comment: @AnujPancholi yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're getting an array of objects form your db in the `del` variable, and each object in that array has the properties `roletoad`, `roletoremove` and `rolelevel`, which you want in separate variables.

For each object of your array, you can store these properties in variables by object [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). One approach is as follows:

```js
//the data you'll get from the db
const del = [{
  roletoad: '735106092308103278',
  roletoremove: '731561814407774248',
  rolelevel: 5
},
{
  roletoad: '735598034385371167',
  roletoremove: '744562691817078905',
  rolelevel: 7
}]


for(const {
  roletoad: yourRoleToAddVar,
  roletoremove: yourRoleToRemoveVar,
  rolelevel: yourRoleToLevelVar
  } of del){
  
  console.log(`Role to add: ${yourRoleToAddVar}`)
  console.log(`Role to remove: ${yourRoleToRemoveVar}`)
  console.log(`Role Level: ${yourRoleToLevelVar}`)
  console.log(`---------------------------`)
  //do what you want with these variables here
  
  }
```

**NOTE:** This should go without saying but the scope of these variables will only be valid within this loop.